# create a cube using Pentaho BI server 7 and schema workbench for Sampledata database

Tags: pentaho, cube, pentaho-data-integration, workbench

I'm trying to create a cube in a pentaho workbench, to the Sampledata database (type: Hypersonic), and publish it in pentaho BI server, but when I try to publish, it cannot be published.
Please, if you have any ideas?  or let me know if you think I made a mistake while creating the schema, and if you have any link for any tutorial that I can follow, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have errors while publishing schema you have created please check the command prompt screen hidden at back of workbench schema UI. CMD Screen should  tell you errors regarding the same.

please check if you have the right hsqldb.jar file at below location
C:\Pentaho\design-tools\schema-workbench\drivers

you can download the latest jar file online.